# Creating a marker with google maps sdk swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, xcode8

I feel like I'm doing something really stupid and the answer is right in front of me. I've tried implementing the ability to tap on the map, which will create a marker at the point tapped, with a title of the address. But whenever I tap on the map nothing happens, there's no error or anything. I even tried using the function longPress but that doesn't work either. Can someone please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

My imports, locationManager, and viewDidLoad

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class EventCreatorVC: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var SearchMap: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!


let marker = GMSMarker()

private lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    return locationManager
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationManager.delegate = self
    mapView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() 
}
```

My map configure:

```
  private func configureMapView() {
    mapView.delegate = self

    // Center on California.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.0, longitude: -120.0, zoom: 6.0)
    mapView.camera = camera

    mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true)
    mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = true

    checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    //addLocationMarkers()
}
```

The 2 functions I have in to try to make it work, the first is long press and the second is just a tap.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

    marker.position = location

    self.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: coordinate, marker: marker)

    marker.map = mapView
}


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

    marker.position = location

    self.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: coordinate, marker: marker)

    marker.map = mapView

}
```

And my reverse GeoCoder

```
func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, marker: GMSMarker) {

    // 1
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in

        //Add this line


        //Rest of response handling
    }

    // 2
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in
        if let address = response?.firstResult() {

            // 3
            let title = address.lines as [String]?
            marker.title = title?.first

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `userinteractionenabled` to true and also write this line into `viewdidload`

```
    let polyLine: GMSPolyline = GMSPolyline()
    polyLine.isTappable = true
    mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mapView.delegate = self
```

And also change your `didTap`method with this one

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        locationOfMarker = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

        marker.position = locationOfMarker

        self.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: coordinate, marker: marker)

        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    }
```